# Twilio Dialogflow is too slow

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es, twilio-twiml

I have integrated Dialogflow with Twilio Number using webhook. Issue that I am facing is the delay. Once the user is saying/asking something it is taking 8-9 sec to get the response back. Not sure if you have faced similar issues but is there any solution for the same. Delaying is causing a big issue and none of the client is up for this.

FYI I am using twilioClient and require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse for all the responses.

Comment: Is there any way to change this solely from the Dialogflow console?

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on, but on the Twilio side which is acting as simple conduit, you can look at [Request Inspector](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136407-Debugging-your-application), to see how many milliseconds it is taking for the request to your application server to return a Twilio Markup Language (TwiML) response, which tells Twilio what to do.

I am not overly familiar with Dialogflow. Twilio offers a multi-channel Natural Language Understanding (NLU) solution, [Autopilot](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/quickstart/node), which can provide an AI bot experience. You could also investigate that solution.

Comment: Hi Alan, Thanks. The issue is when user is saying something, it is waiting for 4-5 sec to call the webhook. I checked the logs.

Comment: There are a timeout you set for the Twilio Gather verb. Either setting speechTimeout to auto or some number of seconds - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#speechtimeout. Once the timeout fires, the action URL is hit.